# Creating a Powershell script for extending AD account expiry dates that gives a choice to extend AD account by either 6 months or by an entered date

Tags: powershell, active-directory, account

I'm a bit of a Powershell noob, so feel free to laugh, I've had some help recently creating some scripts for handling Active Directory account expiration date extensions. In order to meet rigid criteria and increase productivity I'm trying to create a script with specific functionality.

The script asks the user to input a username, the script then checks the username against AD, if it's bad it asks the user to try again, if it's good it proceeds with the next question.

The script then then asks the user to make a choice: 1, extends the account by 6 months and 2, asks the user to input a date, then extends the account by the entered date amount. If there is bad entry, or the date is less than today, the script will ask the user to input the date again.  Once successful both will produce a message showing the date the account has been amended to. After completing the task and displaying the outcome, the script is supposed to start again so the user can amend another account.

The script below **almost** does this. The 6 months option seems to work, but the date entry option seems to be broken. I want the script to ask the user to re-select a choice if they enter an number that is not 1 or 2 when asked to make a selection.
The message for this seems to come up after the user enters a date for option two.

I know I've buggered it up, I've tried various things, but I can't figure out where I've gone wrong. It's probably obvious, but I can't figure it out.

```
$continue = $true

while ($continue) {
    write-host " AD Account Expiration Date Changer" -ForegroundColor White
    Write-Host ""

    while ($true) {
        try {
            # Loop until a valid username is entered
    
            $Entered_Username_0 = Read-Host "Enter a username"
            $Entered_Username = $Entered_Username_0.Trim()
               
            if (Get-ADUser -Identity $Entered_Username | Out-Null) {
                throw
            }
    
            break
        }
        catch {
            Write-Host ""
            Write-Host "Invalid username entered!" -ForegroundColor Red
            Write-Host ""
        }
    }
    $dateMin = [datetime]::Now
    $dateMin_short = $dateMin.ToShortDateString()

    Write-Host "Press 1 to extend the account expiration date by 6 months"
    Write-Host "Press 2 to extend the account expiration date to a sprecific date"
    $Choice_input = Read-Host "Please select an option"
    while ($true) {
        try {
            if ($Choice_input -eq 2) {
                while ($true) {
                    try {
                        # Loop until a valid Date is entered and that Date is above $dateMin

                        $Entered_Date = [datetime]::ParseExact(
                            (Read-Host "Enter a new expiry date, in the format DD/MM/YYYY"),
                            'dd/MM/yyyy',
                            [System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::new('en-GB')
                        )

                        if ($Entered_Date -lt $dateMin) {
                            throw
                        }

                        break

                    }
                    catch {
                        Write-Host ""
                        Write-Host "Invalid date entered! Format must be DD/MM/YYYY and higher than $dateMin_short." -ForegroundColor Red
                        Write-Host ""
                    }
                }
            }
            if ($Choice_input -eq 1) {

                $Entered_Date = [datetime]::Now.addmonths(6)
            }

            else {
                throw
            }

            break
        }
        catch {
            Write-Host ""
            Write-Host "Please input a either 1 or 2." -ForegroundColor Red
            Write-Host ""
        }
    }

    try {
        Set-ADAccountExpiration -Identity $Entered_Username -DateTime $Entered_Date.AddHours(24)
        Write-Host ""
        Write-Host "New account expiration date for $Entered_Username is $(($Entered_Date).toString('dd/MM/yyyy'))"-ForegroundColor Green
        $Entered_Date = ($Entered_date).toString('dd/MM/yyyy')
        Set-ADUser -Identity $Entered_Username -Description "$($_.Description)$Entered_Username contracted to $Entered_Date" -Enabled $true 

    }
    catch {
        Write-Host ""
        Write-Host "Unable to set account expiry: $_"-ForegroundColor Red
    }
    Write-Host ""
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "I want the script to ask the user to re-select a choice if they enter an number that is not 1 or 2 when asked to make a selection." - then you'll need to move the selection menu and `Read-Host` statement into the `while` loop :)

Comment: @mathias-r-jessen Thanks for your reply. Do you mean moving the `read-host` directly underneath  the `$dateMin_short = $dateMin.ToShortDateString()` line to underneath the `while($true){` just below it? Because I did try this and it seemed to do the same thing.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I tried the edited scrips you did and they seem to be repeating the same result as I was getting `Please input a either 1 or 2.` Weird huh?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out:

```
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'
$continue = $true

while ($continue){
    write-host " AD Account Expiration Date Changer" -ForegroundColor White
    Write-Host ""

while($true)
{
        try
        {
            # Loop until a valid username is entered
    
            $Entered_Username_0 = Read-Host "Enter a username"
            $Entered_Username = $Entered_Username_0.Trim()
               
            if (Get-ADUser -Identity $Entered_Username | Out-Null)
            {
                throw
            }
    
            break
        }
        catch
        {
            Write-Host ""
            Write-Host "Invalid username entered!" -ForegroundColor Red
            Write-Host ""
        }
    }
$dateMin = [datetime]::Now
$dateMin_short = $dateMin.ToShortDateString()

$choice_input = ''
while($choice_input -inotin ('1','2')){
    Write-Host "1 to extend the account expiration date by 6 months"
    Write-Host "2 to extend the account expiration date to a sprecific date"
    $choice_input = Read-Host "Please select an option [1, 2]"}

if ($Choice_input -eq 2){
while($true)
{
    try
    {
        # Loop until a valid Date is entered and that Date is above $dateMin

        $Entered_Date = [datetime]::ParseExact(
            (Read-Host "Enter a new expiry date, in the format DD/MM/YYYY"),
            'dd/MM/yyyy',
            [System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::new('en-GB')
        )

        if($Entered_Date -lt $dateMin)
        {
            throw
        }

        break

    }
    catch
    {
        Write-Host ""
        Write-Host "Invalid date entered! Format must be DD/MM/YYYY and higher than $dateMin_short." -ForegroundColor Red
        Write-Host ""
    }
}
}

if ($Choice_input -eq 1){

    $Entered_Date = [datetime]::Now.addmonths(6)
}
try{
    Set-ADAccountExpiration -Identity $Entered_Username -DateTime $Entered_Date.AddHours(24)
    Write-Host ""
    Write-Host "New account expiration date for $Entered_Username is $(($Entered_Date).toString('dd/MM/yyyy'))"-ForegroundColor Green
$Entered_Date = ($Entered_date).toString('dd/MM/yyyy')
Set-ADUser -Identity $Entered_Username -Description "$($_.Description)$Entered_Username contracted to $Entered_Date" -Enabled $true 

}catch{
    Write-Host ""
    Write-Host "Unable to set account expiry: $_"-ForegroundColor Red
}
Write-Host ""
}
```

Comment: Nice! Don't forget to accept your own answer (click the checkmark on the left)!